# Передача оъекта из фрагмента в активити

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity

Есть фрагмент, в котором находится ListView. При клике на элемент списка идет вызов другого активити. Вопрос вот в чем: как передать объект класса из фрагмента в другое активити? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так понимаю, обьект какого-то кастомного класса? Тогда наследуйте его от Parcelable, а после передайте:

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class); 
    intent.putExtra("key", parcelableObject );
    startActivity(intent);

Comment: Спасибо) Вроде бы помогло. А вот про Parcelable я таки забыл :)

Answer (score 1):

Если тебе необходимо **передать объект из фрагмента в активити, которое вызывало фрагмент**, то надо использовать **interface**.

Если же надо **передать из фрагмента в новое активити**, то можно использовать **Parcelable** как указал Hombre, или просто вручную сериализовать объект в строку, переводом в **JSON** и передавать в intent как String